Meter in "Baa Baa Black Sheep"
The Wikipedia page about accentual verse says the nursery rhyme "Baa Baa Black Sheep" is an example of accentual verse and has two stresses per line.
I don't claim to understand prosody well at all, but isn't that wrong?! Maybe it was the way our preschool teacher taught us to recite it, but I would've thought the first line was two spondees. But I do understand that the second 'baa' and 'sheep' are kind of less stressed in comparison with the preceding words, so two trochees is more appropriate.
This is how I would scan the rest of the poem:

Baa, baa, black sheep,
Have you any wool?
Yes sir, yes sir,
Three bags full; [Once again, my first thought was that they're three roughly equally stressed syllables, but not sure anymore]
One for the mas-ter,
And one for the dame,
And one for the lit-tle boy
Who lives down the lane.

I would love to know how others would scan it.

Is this the best example of accentual verse in nursery rhymes? Probably not. There are various ways to scan it, but I think you should put some secondary stress on boy in the line one for the little boy, which means it's not a perfect example of accentual verse.

@PeterShor What about the line “Three bags full”?

If you look at the Hurley and O'Neill analysis of this poem (see Tsundoku's answer), they don't give it just as an example of accentual verse, they give it as an example of dipodic accentual verse with secondary stresses. I would say that your scansion has marked all the secondary stresses as well as the primary ones, while Wikipedia's scansion just marks the primary stresses. So both you and Wikipedia are correct.

Thank you very much, Peter.

@PeterShor I’m not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but do you have any recommendations for books on prosody? I find this topic really fun but frustrating.

The only one that immediately comes to mind is Rhyme's Reason, by John Hollander, but this may not be exactly what you're looking for.

The Wikipedia article is correct. A more authoritative source, Ballad Measure in Print by Bill Gahan on the English Broadside Ballad Archive website (hosted by the University of California at Santa Barbara), scans the nursery rhyme in the same way as the Wikipedia article:

Baa, baa, black sheep,
Have you any wool?
Yes sir, yes sir,
Three bags full;
One for the mas-ter,
And one for the dame,
And one for the lit-tle boy
Who lives down the lane.

The text above the nursery rhyme explains,

Accentual meter is associated with older forms of English verse and song, and nursery rhymes serve to illustrate how stresses can drive the measure, as in “Hickory, Dickory, Dock” or “Baa Baa Black Sheep.” The number of syllables in each line is not important for the rhythm, but the stresses follow a pattern.

The stresses on the first syllable of "any" (second line), "boy" in the penultimate line and "down" in the last line are examples of secondary stresses. Michael D. Hurley and Michael O'Neill point out that this alternation between a heavy (or primary) stress and a lighter (or secondary) stress is known as dipody. They illustrate this with "Baa baa black sheep" (Poetic Form: An Introduction. Cambridge University Press, 2012, page 24).
Below is how Hurley and O'Neill scan the nursery rhyme, with / signs marking heavy stresses and ´ marking light stresses:


Is this really what dipody means? I thought you needed to have more consistent alternations for something to be called dipody, not just occasional ones, as in Baa Baa Black Sheep. Maybe you could include the quote from Hurly and O'Neill where they explain this.

Looking online, I don't believe this would count as dipody in Greek or in Russian. See also the examples of English dipodic poems in this webpage.

@PeterShor How are Greek or Russian relevant if the question is about a very specific nursery rhyme in English?

@PeterShor Quoting from Hurley & O'Neill: "Another notable feature dolnik shares with accentual metre in general is the alternation between a heavy or primary stress (...) and a lighter or 'secondary' stress (...), an effect known as dipody (...)." Followed by Baa baa black sheep as an example of this alternation.

@Tsunduko: Because the only other time I've heard dipodic used in talking about English poetry is this web page, and Baa baa black sheep seems like a rather bad example of the type of poems that they are talking about, which seem to correspond better to its use in Greek poetry. But thinking about it more, maybe I see Hurley & O'Neill's point.

@PeterShor The example of dipodic verse on that page ("I AM the very MODel of a MODern major GENeral") has the kind of alternation between heavy and light stresses mentioned by Hurley and O'Neill. As Stallings writes, "certain strong beats come to the fore, and weaker beats get subsumed". I don't understand how you read that article.

@Tundoku: Never mind. Having thought about it some more, I see that they're right. I was confused because there aren't secondary stresses between every two primary stresses, but you don't really need them.

Thank you so much for the source, Tsundoku.
